# Using custom fonts in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, custom-font

I'm using abeakrg.TTF font. As in other tutorials i put it in assets/fonts

I used this code

```
public class Typefaces {
    private static final String TAG = "Typefaces";

    private final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                            "fonts/abeakrg.TTF");

                    cache.put(assetPath, tf);

                    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                    tv3.setTypeface(tf);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                            + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }

    }
}
```

But when i run it in the emulator or the device the font wont appear. so can i get know the mistake i have done and how to resolve this problem.

Comment: @SimplePlan I used it and it gives an error saying context can not be resolved

Comment: here your Context object is c so try like `c.getAssets()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a subclass from Textview class and settypeface as follow and use in xml

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setTypeface(Utils.getTypeface(context));
    }

    public MyTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(context);
    }

    public MyTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(context);
    }

}




public class Utils {
    private static Typeface tf;
public static Typeface getTypeface(Context ctx) {
        if (tf == null) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf");
        }
        return tf;
    }

    public static Typeface getDolphinTypeface(Context ctx) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/GOTHIC.TTF");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `TypeFace`

for example: if i have **xyz_font.ttf** style then i will set it like this.

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/xyz_font.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

You need put your **xyz_font.ttf file** in **assets/fonts** folder not in **res** folder.

Answer (score 0):

see this custom `TextView` class

**Step 1:**
create one class `CustomTextView`

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

static HashMap<Integer, Typeface> typefaces = new HashMap<Integer, Typeface>(
        5);

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomTextView);

    String typefacename = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_typeface);

    if (typefacename != null) {
        try {

            Typeface typeface = typefaces.get(typefacename.hashCode());

            if (typeface == null) {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                        typefacename);
                typefaces.put(typefacename.hashCode(), typeface);
            }

            this.setTypeface(typeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

 public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

}
```

**Step 2:**

create `attrs.xml` in value folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
   <attr name="typeface" format="string" />
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**step 3** Copy required fonts into the assets folder of your project

**step 4:** Instead of  TextView, use CustomTextView.java in your layout (you can find your customTextView in XML layout editor in custom view  section )

use custom `TextView` like this

```
  <com.your.path.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="custom font"
    app:typeface="your_font.ttf" />
```